# How to render a div element several times using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have  div element which I want to render several times for each element of the array in React. Right now I am rendering a component using the map method but how to render a div in that manner. This is how I render the component

```
<div class="expndmid">
{
    this.state.shopd.map((cat) => (<ShopsCatOptions shop={cat}/>))                
}
</div>
```

How to render a div in that manner instead of creating a component I want to render the data(`this.state.shopd`) inside the div. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="expndmid">
{
   this.state.shopd.map((cat) => (
      <div shop={cat}> {cat} </div>
   ))  
}
</div>
```